# Linux gcc <time.h> and threads together

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I seem to be in a catch-22. My program uses threads and semaphores so I have included `<semaphore.h>` but I also want to use `struct timespec` so I've included `<time.h>`.

It seems I need to add the compile flag -C99 so my semaphore calls are defined (otherwise I get compile warnings undefined on the likes of `sem_post()`). But when I define C99, `struct timespec` is no longer defined!

What defines or compiler flags do I need to set to use `struct timespec` and functions such as `clock_gettime()`, define `CLOCK_REALTIME`, `sem_timedwait()` along with `sem_post()`, `sem_destroy()`, etc?

I haven't got to the link stage yet. This is a compile time error.

Using gcc 4.4.7.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: You are unlikely to find a header that defines `sme_post()`.

Comment: Sorry - I pointed to the wrong set of issues. I needed to NOT have -std=c99 but do have -pthread and link with -lpthreads. Complicating I am calling clock_gettime() so I also need to link with rt. My first question and I flubbed it. Mike

Comment: Not getting you. Can you edit and rephrase the question?

Comment: Thank you Mike. You are correct. I'd read somewhere else that the -std=c99 was required and that had me down the incorrect path.

Comment: per the man page for `sem_post()` there are no conditional macros that need to be defined to use it, so which level of the standard you use in the compile step should make no difference.

Comment: for the `clock_gettime()` function, your code will need to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` with a value greater than or equal to 199309L  I.E.  `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  199309L`  and the linking with `-rt` is only needed for `glibc` versions before 2.17

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `-std=c99` for `sem_post()` etc - those are POSIX functions.

The only command-line argument you should need for both `clock_gettime()` etc and `sem_post()` etc is `-lrt`.

Comment: Thank you. This did work for me; Removing the compile flag -std=c99 adding compile flag -pthread, adding link libs -lpthreads and -lrt.